# Video controls scroll when page scrolls in react-native-video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, android-videoview, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video in which I am playing video for card in a list of multiple cards. This is working fine in iOS but the issue is with Android. Firstly it shows blank screen when video loaded when I click on that space and then controls got visible. When I click on controls video started playing and at the same time if I scroll my page video controls scroll as per page scrolled and then got invisible. I want to stop this behaviour. The controls must immediately gets disappeared when list scroll. I tries many props and method of this library along with react-native-media-controls but all in vain. I have followed Android Installation Documentation of this library.

Code for video

```
 <Video
            controls={true}
           
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{uri: item.image}} // Can be a URL or a local file.
            playInBackground={false}
            repeat={false}
            paused={true}
            playWhenInactive={false}
            style={{
              width: width * 0.86,
              height: height * 0.3,
              borderRadius: 12,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              marginTop: previewMode ? width * 0.05 : 0,
            }}
          />
```

Link for issue : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycqQIRfKN4A5OcdxmcsGwsnm81_GXGrK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if you resolved this issue then please let me know ?

Comment: @deepanshi gupta did you solve it ? 
Please let me know the solution